# What is the meaning of "Bussin' juugs"?

Tags: meaning, slang

I've been listening to trap music lately and I came across Gucci Mane's ["Bussin' juugs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W37wyVdxKZU). There is a lot of slang in the lyrics of trap music and given that I'm not a native speaker I didn't understand the title of the song.

Googling I've found that "juug" is "profiting from ilegal activities". What is the meaning of that expression  then? Being too busy from getting profit from ilegal activities?

Comment: From urban dictionary - [**bussin**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bussin) *- to look real cute or have a nice body*, [**jugs**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jugs) *- a woman's breasts. Especially when large and shapely.* But they also have [**juug**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Juug) *Act of profiting off illegal or legal activities. Involves scheming, lying or tricking other party for a larger financial gain*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think song lyrics are off topic

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with you, @FumbleFingers. Could one explain the lyrics "I cry when angels deserve to die" or "wired were the eyes of a horse on a jet pilot, when he flew over the bay"? It's all too open to interpretation. Is there an example outside of song lyrics where "bussin' juugs" is used? That context would be far more informative.

Comment: I think the phrase "bussin' juugs" is being used literally here (not poetically, as @Matt's examples are). It's meaning is compositional on its constituents, "bussin" and "juugs." It's thus a question of what these individual slang words mean, a valid one about usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe song lyrics interpretation is on topic at http://musicfans.stackexchange.com if someone wants to migrate it.  With that said, this is really a question about slang terminology, not lyrics interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not asking for an interpretation of the lyrics. I just linked to the video to give context on where I found the expression, but I think that it can be explained without any reference to the song.

Comment: I agree with Chris Sunami and Adolfo that, on the face of it, the question is about a slang phrase. It may be that the phrase is "literary or poetical"—that is, juxtaposed as a matter of art and not a phrase that would be found in everyday discourse in the real world; but my presumption for so short a phrase is that it means something simple and definite, and is either a set phrase or two slang terms that might very well be used consecutively in real-world English speech. Questions about the meaning of such terms are clearly on topic, if questions about slang are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***bussin*** should be interpreted as ***busting*** (it's written as "bustin" on Gucci Mane's t-shirt in the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W37wyVdxKZU) of the song).

***juugs*** is also sometimes spelled ***joogs***. I believe it derives from the word "drug". As a noun, it seems to mean something like a *small-time drug dealer*, or the *act of selling a small quantity of drugs*. It can also be used as a verb which means *to engage in the activities of a small-time drug dealer* (for example, when Gucci says "I juug so good").

It is used in all of these ways in the song:

- You're just another ***juug*** [small-time dealer].
- I ***juug*** [sell small quantities of drugs] so good.
- When I came back to the city ***bussin juugs*** [committing small-time drug deals]

In the song, Gucci Mane seems to be describing his life as a small-time drug dealer. In the chorus, his girlfriend says to him that he's "just another damn juug," to which Gucci responds that he's more like a ***plug***, a higher-up drug dealer or supplier.